# How can I serialize Array of JSON with arrays from a file in path?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, nsjsonserialization, jsonserializer

I have a .json file into my Xcode project using Swift. 
I need load the content and parse to use in my controller, butn when I try serialize the file content to an jsonObject I'm getting errors parsing...

I have read another similar questions but I haven't found a similar Array of JSON to read with different structures contained and another Array of JSON into the object.

The format of array JSON is:

```
[
  {
    "title": "The App",
    "description": "This is the description",
    "friends": [
      {
        "name": "Gary",
        "image": "http://",
        "description": "Nice"
      },
      {
        "name": "Patri",
        "image": "http://",
        "description": "Amazing"
      },
      {
        "name": "Lucy",
        "image": "http://",
        "description": "Up"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm using this code to get the content of file from bundle path(data.json added to my proyect) and then serialize, but always get an error because Friends contains an array of json.

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "json")
let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
let jsonResult = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as? [[String:Any]] //Here is the error parsing the array of Friend of JSON
```

How can I parse this array of json that contains another array of jsonObjects?

Comment: Something else seems wrong. Even though it contains JSON objects in an array, this still should be perfectly valid JSON and parseable

Comment: You should look at implementing `Codable` instead. And don't do `try!`, take the time to implement some proper error handling

Comment: @Mike you were right, a text of the item description friends had invalid characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Codable`

```
// MARK: - Element
struct Root: Codable {
    let title, purpleDescription: String
    let friends: [Friend]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case purpleDescription = "description"
        case friends
    }
}

// MARK: - Friend
struct Friend: Codable {
    let name, image, friendDescription: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, image
        case friendDescription = "description"
    }
}
```

---

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "data", withExtension: "json")
let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf:url)
let res = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self,from:data)
print(res)
```

Comment: `try!`, really?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the json is local , there is no availability for a crash , it's a matter of 1 run to verify it'll go successfully , in general `!` isn't dangerous if the developer knows when to use it

Comment: Yes but given the question I think that OP is not that experienced so a proper error handling is more suitable.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson You are right, but reading you both I understood that I should deal with the error if the JSON received it from a service that might not arrive. A text contained invalid characters, so my method did not work. But I give the answer as correct because it works and is a new way for me using Codable. Thanks!